# reverse proxy to distinct internal servers

Tags: ubuntu, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

At our institution we have single static public IP but multiple applications hosted for internet access. In an attempt to access application on different internal servers through a single server found reverse proxy can do this job.
The following is the current requirement:
[image]

In order to achieve this we have installed Apache and Nginx (Ubuntu 20) as illustrated [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-web-server-and-reverse-proxy-for-apache-on-one-ubuntu-18-04-server#step-6-installing-and-configuring-nginx). But unfortunately the reverse proxy is not working as expected. Although no errors in the installation, the direction does not happen.

```
server  {
    listen  443 ssl;
    server_name domaina.com;
    ssl  on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domaina.com.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domaina.com.key;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    location  / {
            proxy_pass  https://10.10.60.18/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

}

```
server  {
        listen  443 ssl;
        server_name domainb.com;
        ssl  on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainb.com.cer;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainb.com.key;
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
        location  / {
                proxy_pass  https://10.10.60.30/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

With the above settings this does not happen.
Not sure our approach is correct, is there any right approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Found a super-duper solution for this.
Just download and install Nginx Proxy Manager from https://nginxproxymanager.com/
This can run as a docker therefore no need to install any dependency. This is all-in-one package. Just download and run.
then open the application set 'proxy host' using very easy to use GUI.
Complete guide is available here: https://nginxproxymanager.com/guide/#project-goal